# Add keyboard shortcut to open Builds view in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I am wondering if there is Visual Studio command for showing the Builds view in Team Explorer, so that I can bind a keyboard shortcut to it. 
For example, I was able to create <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> shortcut bound to View.TfsPendingChanges command which shows directly Pending Changes view within Team Explorer.

EDIT: 
As it is not obvious from the answer, the command TeamFoundationContextMenus.Commands.GoToBuilds is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command. Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Build.ViewControllerQueue is the one you want, but if you set a shortcut and try to execute it, you get:

> The key combination (combination) is bound to command (View Controller Queue) which is not currently available.

I'm not sure how to get around this. The easiest way I've found to get to the Build Explorer so far is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> which brings up the Builds page of the Team Explorer, and then you can hit Actions > Manage Queue.

Interestingly, if you set the shortcut as described above, it will actually show up in the Actions context menu as the shortcut, but it does not work.

Comment: Well, actually TeamFoundationContextMenus.Commands.GoToBuilds (the one by default bound to CTRL+0,B is the command I was looking for.