# What is the hotkey to open Build explorer in Team Explorer pane in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

Currently to get to Build page, we open Team Explorer and hit Home button and go for Build.

What is the hotkey for that?

Comment: [Google must've been broken](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+hotkey+Build+explorer+in+Team+Explorer) when you tried searching for this, huh? ;) [This seems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/06/06/team-explorer-2012-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx) to be the closest you can get (also [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13612167/1454048)).

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. Please put your comment into an answer to get accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Naw don't worry about it, since it was already answered on SO. Glad to help, though!

Answer (score 0):

(from user admdrew)

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/06/06/team-explorer-2012-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx) seems to be the closest you can get (also [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13612167/1454048) here).